# C# MVC HTML to EXCEL not working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, excel

I had a controller method to convert html to excel which worked fine when it was not a web method. But stopped working when the html string got too large. I converted it to a web method which I call via jQuery. It passes the data to the method, but no longer creates the Excel file. The code within the method has not changed. The only difference is the way I call it and the [HttpPost] decoration. The code follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public void ExportExcel(string aContent)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(aContent);

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ProjectData.xls");
        Response.Write(sb);
        Response.End();
    }
```

And this is the jQuery stuff:

```
// namespace
var excel = excel || {};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ExcelUrl').on('click', function () {
        var table = $('#tableName').val();
        var content = $('#' + table).html();
        excel.utilFunctions.exportToExcel(content);
    });
});

excel.utilFunctions = (function ($) {
    var exportToExcel = function (content) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/ExportExcel",
            type: "POST",
            data: { aContent: content }
        }).done(function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }).fail(function(error) {
            alert(error.responseText);
        });
    };

    //public functions
    return {
        exportToExcel: exportToExcel
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Apparently, since jQuery is doing the post, a file will never be generated no matter what you do.

I changed the jQuery function to create and submit a hidden form field that has my data in it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ExcelUrl').on('click', function () {
        var table = $('#tableName').val();
        var content = $('#' + table).html().replace(/\s/g, "");
        excel.utilFunctions.exportToExcel(content);
    });
});

excel.utilFunctions = (function ($) {
    // Excel export function
    var exportToExcel = function (content) {
        var form = $("<form></form>");
        form.attr("method", "POST");
        form.attr("action", "/Home/ExportExcel");
        var dataField = $("<input/>");
        dataField.attr("type", "hidden");
        dataField.attr("name", "aContent");
        dataField.attr("value", content);
        form.append(dataField);
        $(document.body).append(form);
        form.submit();
    };

    //public functions
    return {
        exportToExcel: exportToExcel
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Then I changed the ExportExcel controller function to return a FileStreamResult

```
 public FileStreamResult ExportExcel(string aContent)
```

and modified the code that does the actual exporting

```
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(aContent);
var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

return File(stream, "application/ms-excel", "FileName.xls");
```